# IP to long conversion c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scanf

I am trying to convert an IP string to long in `c++`,
and I prefer not to use any of `inet`'s functions.

I am converting it with the following function:

```
unsigned long IPStringToLong(std::string IPAddr)
{
        unsigned char aClassByte, bClassByte, cClassByte, dClassByte;
        sscanf_s(IPAddr.c_str(), IP_TO_BYTES_FORMAT, &aClassByte, &bClassByte, &cClassByte, &dClassByte);
        unsigned long IP = (aClassByte << 24) | (bClassByte << 16) | (cClassByte << 8) | dClassByte;
        std::cout << IP << std::endl;
        return IP;
}
```

`IP_TO_BYTES_FORMAT` is defined here:

`#define IP_TO_BYTES_FORMAT "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu"`

The printing is just for debugging.

Visual studio throws a Run-Time error: `Stack corruption around variable bClassByte`, but the conversion does work.

When I define the format to `short`s (and change the code of course):

`#define IP_TO_BYTES_FORMAT "%hu.%hu.%hu.%hu"`

it works just fine, and I can't understand why.

Comment: `"%hh"` is not a valid format. Do you mean `"%hu"`?

Comment: sscanf class functions are NOT typesafe with arguments. %u format require pointer to integer, You give pointer to char (byte), sscanf function doest know this. Next variable is destroyed (debug version of runtime give warning)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yep, thanks!

Comment: @JacekCz still don't understand why it is working fine with short

Comment: "errors in pair", one hide (mask) effect of other

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `%hhu` is a valid format. It's just not a valid format in C89.

Comment: short can be (depends on architecture) same size as int

Comment: @JacekCz: True, but even then you still need the right `scanf` specifier. It's not just size but also trap bits.

Comment: Aside: The function should better be called `IPv4StringToLong` and the parameter `IPv4Addr` because it will fail when called with an IPv6 address string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're using C++, but you're actually calling  a C function. That is the cause of your problem: you've found a bit of C99 code. `%hhu` is C99. Your Visual Studio version doesn't implement C99.

The fix is easy, since you need to fix a bit more anyway. Don't use `short` either; the dotted-quad format allows `8.24` and `8.8.16` as well. In other word, you need `%d.%d.%d.%d`, and a check how many fields you actually read (return value of `scanf`). And while we're doing it right, we might as well use `int parts[4]` instead of `a,b,c,d`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't completley understand your note about the dotted-quad format allows 8.24 and so on. Could you point me to some reading?

Comment: @OferArial: See wikipedia. Basically, `10.1234567` is a valid address in the `10.x.x.x` range. To convert that to a long, you calculate `(10<<24) + 1234567`. And you can't fit `1234567` in a short.

Comment: @OferArial: an IPv4 address can be expressed in one of 4 different formats: `a.b.c.d`, `a.b.c`, `a.b`, and `a`.  And each individual number can itself be expressed in decimal (most common), hex, or octal format. [`inet_addr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563.aspx) and other similar functions handle all of these formats for you. Read the `inet_addr()` documentation for a good summary of what these formats represent. The code you showed only supports `a.b.c.d` in decimal format, which is the most common format used, but certainly not the only format available.